# Do PDOStatement::fetch* methods pull content from memory or the database server?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am using MySQL as my database server. I am currently trying to optimise my application when I came across a question I could not find an adequate answer to.

I use PDO::query to execute a statement which returns a PDOStatement object. What I would like to know is whether methods such as PDOStatement::fetch/fetchAll etc are querying/pulling their content from the database server or elsewhere such as memory.

Comment: [look at this page in the manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.concepts.buffering.php), it applies to buffered/unbuffered queries in PDO as well. In short: usually the result set is in the memory of the PHP process, unless you tell it explicitly to fetch it unbuffered from the database itself.

Comment: Thank you, an informative link.